# Make Label Wicket invisible

Tags: java, label, wicket

I tried to hide a label as follows :

```
  Form form = new Form("form");

  Label myLabel = new Label("myLabel", new ResourceModel("mylabel.text").getObject());
  if(hide == true){
        myLabel.setVisible(Boolean.FALSE);
  }
  form.add(myLabel);

  ..
```

but the label still appears. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should override the isVisible method of your label.

```
Label label = new Label(...) {
  @Override
  public boolean isVisible() {
    return !hide;
  }
};
form.add(...)
...
```

Comment: Just as a side note: the isVisible() method may be called a few times in the rendering process. No expensive computation / hitting the database schould be done in there. Wicket 1.5 introduced a new method for this that will only be called once.

Comment: @magomi Does it technique also apply to other components in wicket too? Things like textarea, textbox, button, etc.

Comment: Yes. isVisible(...) is a method of Component, from which all UI components are derived.

Comment: If you're using Wicket 1.4.x, override the `onConfigure()` method and do a standard `this.setVisible(!hide)`.  This is recommended in various places, though not (if I recall) in the JavaDoc.

Comment: The javadoc of Component#onConfigure() says it all.

Comment: @jbrookover - Why the restriction to 1.4.x?  Would you use something different with Wicket 1.5.x+?

Comment: @Snekse Haven't used 1.5 yet, so I don't know if there is something else.  I wouldn't think, so, though.  `onConfigure()` was introduced late in the 1.4.x family, though, and is only called once as bert mentions above.

Answer (score 0):

actually you are making invisible the label, the problem is redraw the html page,what  you can do it refreshing the page or with help of ajax

Comment: This makes sense if the condition whether show or hide the label changes after an ajax call. Then call setVisible(...). After that add the label to the AjaxRequestTarget an it will redrawn. In the original sample the label is still not. It is just about to be initialized. In this case its better to override the isVisible(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

Informations below are for Wicket 1.4 (quite old now).

For Wicket 1.5 and 6.x (aka 1.6) the right way is override component's  `onConfigure()` and call `setVisible()` from there:

```
@Override
protected void onConfigure()
{
    super.onConfigure();
    boolean flag = myDbDAO.getVisibilityOfThisPanel()
    this.setVisible(flag);
}
```

Keep `component.isVisible()` light, it should be called more than once per request so long-computing-task there will slow page/panel loading. Put heavy process (DB, math) in `onConfigure()` and from there call `isVisible()` if needed.